# How to put a text file into a 2d list in tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples, 2d

I am having a problem with passing a text file into a 2 dimensional array of tuples. Here is what my input file looks like, it's really big so this is just part of it.

`26 54 94 25 53 93 24 52 92 25 53 93 25 53 93 25 53 93 25 53 93 27 55 95 28 55 98 26 53 96 25 52 95 26 53 96 27 54 97 28 55 98 27 54 97 26 53 96 26 55 97 26 55 97 26 55 97 26 55 97 25 54 96 25 54 96 25 54 96 26 55 97 26 55 99 27 56 100 28 57 101 26 55 99 25 54 98 26 55 99 26 55 99 26 55 99 25 54 98 26 55 99 27 56 100 27 56 100 26 55 99 26 55 99 26 55 99 27 56 100 28 57 101 29 58 102 29 58 102`

Here is the function that is reading in the file and putting it in the 2d array

```
def load_image_data(infile):
    '''
    Accepts an input file object
    Reads the data in from the input PPM image into a 2-dimensional list of RGB tuples
    Returns the 2-dimensional list
    '''
    print("Loading image data...\n")

    for line in infile.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        values = line.split(" ")
        new_line = []
        for j in range(int(len(new_line) / 3) + 1):
            for i in range(len(new_line) // 3):
                r = new_line[0]
                g = new_line[1]
                b = new_line[2]
                t = (r, g, b)

                t_list.append(t)
                del new_line[0]
                del new_line[0]
                del new_line[0]

                new_line.append(t)
        print(new_line)
        print("done")
        return new_line`
```

And here is `main`:

```
def main():
    '''
    Runs Program
    '''

    mods = ["vertical_flip", "horizontal_flip", "horizontal_blur", "negative",
            "high_contrast", "random_noise", "gray_scale", "remove_color"]
            # ** finish adding string modifications to this list
    for mod in mods:

        # get infile name
        #file = (input("Please enter the input file name: "))

        # get outfile name
        #out = (input("Please enter the output file name: "))

        infile = open("ny.ppm", "r") # ** get the filename from the user
        outfile = open("ny_negative.ppm", "w") # ** change to use mod and user-spec filename

        process_header(infile, outfile)
        load_image_data(infile)
        process_body(infile, outfile, mod)

        outfile.close()
        infile.close()
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: a blank array is being printed instead of [(1,2,3) , (1,2,3() ... etc] @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Also, what is the expected output corresponding to the input you gave?

Comment: what is your process_header and process_body function?

Comment: So, just looking at your code, your outer loop is over `range(int(len(new_line)/3) +1)` and your inner loop is over `for i in range(len(new_line) // 3)`. But the `new_line` is `[]`, so the outer loop does one iteration, but the inner loop does none, since `len(new_line) == 0`, which is good, since `r = new_line[0]` would throw an `IndexError`, not sure what you are expecting....

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran the process header is because the first 3 lines of the text file are different from the body, I did not add that portion to the code given above

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I can change the loops if needed, but I am pretty stuck, so I posted my latest attempt. The text file is a bunch of RGB values from an image, so that is why I need to get them into tuples so that I can manipulate the numbers of RGB. I could totally just be approaching this the wrong way

Comment: You need to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case, while you have an example input, you haven't given the corresponding output.

Comment: The output would be [(26, 54, 94), (25, 53, 93) ..... ] through the whole file. Thats what I tried to explain above. Sorry if I was unclear @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: as @juanpa.arrivillaga has pointed, you make new_line=[] and the iterate through the range of len of empty list! Therefore the statements inside the loop goes unexecuted

Answer (score 0):

read the data from your file as inf and the split it to get the list of data. With that, iterate through the items for range(number_of_items//3) and then get the desired length appended to your list and return the same!

```
print("Loading image data...\n")

inf=infile.readlines()
inf = inf[0].split()
new_line=[]
for i in range(len(inf)//3):
    r,b,g=inf[i*3:i*3+3]
    print r,g,b
    t = (r, g, b)
    t_list.append(t)
    new_line.append(inf[i*3:i*3+3])
return new_line
```

And in your main()

```
infile = open("ny.ppm", "r") # ** get the filename from the user
print load_image_data(infile)
infile.close()
```

Sample Output:

```
[['26', '54', '94'], ['25', '53', '93'], ['24', '52', '92'], ['25', '53', '93'], ['25', '53', '93'], ['25', '53', '93'], ['25', '53', '93'], ['27', '55', '95'], ['28', '55', '98'], ['26', '53', '96'], ['25', '52', '95'], ['26', '53', '96'], ['27', '54', '97'], ['28', '55', '98'], ['27', '54', '97'], ['26', '53', '96'], ['26', '55', '97'], ['26', '55', '97'], ['26', '55', '97'], ['26', '55', '97'], ['25', '54', '96'], ['25', '54', '96'], ['25', '54', '96'], ['26', '55', '97'], ['26', '55', '99'], ['27', '56', '100'], ['28', '57', '101'], ['26', '55', '99'], ['25', '54', '98'], ['26', '55', '99'], ['26', '55', '99'], ['26', '55', '99'], ['25', '54', '98'], ['26', '55', '99'], ['27', '56', '100'], ['27', '56', '100'], ['26', '55', '99'], ['26', '55', '99'], ['26', '55', '99'], ['27', '56', '100'], ['28', '57', '101'], ['29', '58', '102'], ['29', '58', '102']]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The output it gave me was just the numbers 26 54 94

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could chunk into tuples:

```
In [8]: from itertools import islice

In [9]: with open("yourfile.DATA") as f:
    ...:    data = f.read().split()
    ...:    size = len(data)
    ...:    it = map(int, data)
    ...:    data = [tuple(islice(it,0,3)) for _ in range(0, size, 3)]
    ...:
```

The output:

```
In [10]: data
Out[10]:
[(26, 54, 94),
 (25, 53, 93),
 (24, 52, 92),
 (25, 53, 93),
 (25, 53, 93),
 (25, 53, 93),
 (25, 53, 93),
 (27, 55, 95),
 (28, 55, 98),
 (26, 53, 96),
 (25, 52, 95),
 (26, 53, 96),
 (27, 54, 97),
 (28, 55, 98),
 (27, 54, 97),
 (26, 53, 96),
 (26, 55, 97),
 (26, 55, 97),
 (26, 55, 97),
 (26, 55, 97),
 (25, 54, 96),
 (25, 54, 96),
 (25, 54, 96),
 (26, 55, 97),
 (26, 55, 99),
 (27, 56, 100),
 (28, 57, 101),
 (26, 55, 99),
 (25, 54, 98),
 (26, 55, 99),
 (26, 55, 99),
 (26, 55, 99),
 (25, 54, 98),
 (26, 55, 99),
 (27, 56, 100),
 (27, 56, 100),
 (26, 55, 99),
 (26, 55, 99),
 (26, 55, 99),
 (27, 56, 100),
 (28, 57, 101),
 (29, 58, 102),
 (29, 58, 102)]
```

That list comprehension could be written a little more verbosely as:

```
In [11]: with open('yourfile.DATA') as f:
    ...:    data = f.read().split()
    ...:    size = len(data)
    ...:    it = map(int, data)
    ...:    data = []
    ...:    for _ in range(0, size, 3):
    ...:        data.append(tuple(islice(it, 0, 3)))
    ...:
```

Note that I used a `with` block, which is advisable when dealing with files, not only do they close the file for you, but they make *sure* the file is closed (in case of an exception handling even, for example).

One piece of advice, *be careful passing file-handlers around*. When you do stuff like this:

```
infile = open("ny.ppm", "r") # ** get the filename from the user
outfile = open("ny_negative.ppm", "w") # ** change to use mod and user-spec filename

process_header(infile, outfile)
load_image_data(infile)
process_body(infile, outfile, mod)

outfile.close()        
infile.close()
```

Be aware that file handlers like `infile` act sort of like one-pass iterators, and can only do stuff like `.readlines()` once. So if you use `infile.readlines()` in `process_header`, when you pass that same `infile` to `process_body`, subsequent calls to `infile.readlines()` will raise an error unless unless you reset the file cursor explicitly using `infile.seek(0)` -- which is why I say they are "sort of" like one-pas iterators. But I suggest not dealing with that and instead passing around a string of the path to the file, and using a `with`-block to open your files.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would read (and return) the image data as a list-of-lists-of-tuples:

```
try:
    from itertools import izip
except ImportError:  # Python 3
    izip = zip

def load_image_data(infile):
    rows = []
    for line in infile:
        values = [int(v) for v in line.split()]
        tuples = [t for t in izip(*[iter(values)]*3)]
        rows.append(tuples)

    return rows

def main():
    with open("ny.ppm", "r") as infile, open("ny_negative.ppm", "w") as outfile:
        process_header(infile, outfile)
        image_data = load_image_data(infile)
        print(image_data)
        # etc ...

main()
```

Sample of output format:

```
[[(255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255), ...], 
 [(255, 255, 0), (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 0), ...],
    ...
]
```